# Split is not a function: Trying to get response from api through GET using ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I want to use `get` method to get some response from API using ngResource.

I have created a factory for my resource but when I use the factory in my controller it throws error `URL.split is not a function`. I don't understand what the problem is in my code.

```
var Myapp = angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngResource'])
    .config(['$resourceProvider', function ($resourceProvider) {
            $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
        }]);
Myapp.factory('Users', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('some URL', {}, {
       query: {
          method: 'GET'
       }
    });
});
Myapp.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Users', function ($scope, $state, Users) {
    Users.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error is: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
    });

}])
```

Comment: Can you share the complete error thrown?

Comment: Error: url.split is not a function

Comment: this is the error i got through development tool.

Answer (score 0):

you injected 3 items('$scope', '$state', 'Users') but send 4 items to function ($scope, $state, $http, Users). you should delete `$http`

```
Myapp.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Users', function ($scope, $state, Users) {
    Users.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error is: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
    });

}])
```

Comment: this is by mistake while posting my problem over stack overflow i have deleted it but still i got this error i know i have done some silly mistake but not able to get it.please get me out of this.